# Laravel Sendgrid SMTP not working

Tags: php, laravel, sendgrid

I am trying to use Sendgrid SMTP to send out regular Mail:: emails. But they are not going through, not seeing any sent emails on my Sendgrid dashboard, but getting no errors either.

It did work and still does if I change it to Gmail SMTP information.

Any advice on what I could look at?

Mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'ssl://smtp.sendgrid.net'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', ''),

'username' => env('sendgrid_username'),

'password' => env('sendgrid_password'),
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sendgrid_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgrid_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="name"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=no-reply@email.com
```

Comment: Long shot - remove the double quotes from MAIL_FROM_NAME. Docs say it's only needed if there's a space in the value.

Comment: I removed the name for this post, it does have a space in it on the actual live setup.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you:

> Set your **username** to string *apikey*.  Set your **password** to the actual API key
>   generated.

as per [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html)

Answer (score 0):

from official docs : https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=sendgrid_username
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgrid_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use user name as API key for all APIs.

MAIL_USERNAME=apikey

Answer (score -1):

I realise this is an old question but for those googling, setting
`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp` should work.

Answer (score -3):

MAIL_USERNAME is your username MAIL_PASSWORD is your password, MAIL_DRIVER=smtp, MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net and MAIL_PORT=587.
If you want to send transactional emails with sendgrid then use this example https://usingphp.com/post/send-transactional-email-with-sendgrid-in-laravel